# Normalization in PostgreSQL - share a primary key across tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-normalization, dbml

I'm designing a PostgreSQL database that involves three tables: `buys`, `sells`, and `transaction_pairs`. In each of the `buys` and `sells` tables I have a unique identifier column `id`.

[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdYQf.png)

In the `pairs` table, I have `buy_id` and `sell_id` columns which act as foreign keys to the `id` fields of the `buys` and `sells` tables respectively. The `transaction_pairs` table:

| id | filing_year | buy_id | sell_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2020 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2020 | 4 | 4 |

The `id` values in the `pairs` table correspond to the same `id` values in the `buys` and `sells` tables. Therefore I'm considering whether I can eliminate redundancy by sharing a primary key across all three tables.

(The reason these numbers match is I'm splitting the original transactions to pair buys with sells. Hence the one-to-many relationship(s) with the `raw_transactions` table and the three `buys`, `sells` and `transaction_pairs` having the same number of rows.)

I'm trying to avoid merging all of the information into a single table if possible, but I also want to avoid duplicating information.

Is it good practice to share a primary key across multiple tables in this way, and if so, how should I implement this in PostgreSQL?

I'm also interested in how to document this kind of relationship in DBML.

To reduce redundancies, I tried creating a composite key in the `transaction_pairs` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "transaction_pairs" (
  "buy_id" INT,
  "sell_id" INT,
  "filing_year" INT,
  PRIMARY KEY ("buy_id", "sell_id")
);
```

However, there is a remaining redundancy in that buy_id and sell_id will always have the same value.

Can we reduce it further?

Comment: Why not have the `transaction_pairs` have the `buy_id` and `sell_id` be FK's to the `raw_transactions` table?

Comment: Because in my use case (crypto tax reporting), I need to split raw transactions further. 

For example, suppose you buy 2 BTC at two different prices (1) $30k , and (2) $60k. Then, you sell 0.5 BTC @ 45k (3) totaling 3 raw transactions. 

To optimize for losses, the sell transaction will be reported identically in `sells` but the paired buy will come from the second `raw_transaction` @ 60k and it will only represent 0.5 of the total amount bought [to show a loss of 0.5 * (60k - 45k)]. 

Hence the `transaction_pairs` refer to the `buys` and `sells` table and not `raw_transactions`.

Comment: And I can have situations where the sell is split too. In general, there will be many more rows in `buys` and `sells` than in `raw_transactions`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have two identical tables (buy and sells). You can normalise it further, you can have a single primary key, being referenced as foreign key in all other tables.

For instance: Have another table having common information of "buy" and "sells" table. Each row in this table will have unique id(primary key), which will be a foreign key in other tables.

Also: 100% database normalisation is not achievable.

Comment: Hmm I could make a primary key in `transaction_pairs` then reference it as a foreign key in `buys` and `sells`. My follow up question would be if it is okay for a table (e.g. `buys`) to have no primary key (?)